# display all posts in wordpress admin

Tags: posts, admin

Is there any reason why Wordpress restricts the amount of posts you can administer at once to 20?

Is there a way to display all posts?

I want to change the category for about 1800 posts.

I don't have the ability to change the post amount under screen options; see here: tinyurl.com/3npm5yz

Using WP v3.1.3

Comment: yes you do, check the 'posts' page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't, in the top right under screen options it says, **Show on screen**, you can set this to a max of 999 ( I have never tried 999 just fyi) and you can select all, then bulk actions--->edit--->apply.

[image]

Also I think there are plugins that do this that use direct `wpdb` functions, so you can effectively do it to more posts at once.

Comment: ah you were faster than me :) I had a screenshot ready if it helps http://i.stack.imgur.com/VPua7.png

Comment: LOL at your screenshot. I wish I could make your comment the right answer.

Comment: I am using v3.1.3 and I don't have the ability to change the post count that you have.  See http://tinyurl.com/3npm5yz

Comment: @Steve the screenshot you provided is apparently taken from Dashboard. *Screen Options* dropdown is contextual. Go to your posts edit screen a try again.