# Change pagination in editing posts

Tags: admin, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display all posts in wordpress admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/display-all-posts-in-wordpress-admin)

How do I increase the pagination limit in the edit posts admin section (edit.php)?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is NOT clear. Rewrite your question by adding more details, and try to make it as much clear as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the edit posts page, click on 'Screen Options' on the top right, and you can enter a value for the amount of posts per page.